# performSelector throws UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I was developing my application on XCode 4.1, for iOs 4.3, but yesterday I've updated it to XCode 4.2 with iOs 5.0 SDK.

When I run my application in iphone 4.3 simulator, it works great.
I decided to test it on iphone 5.0 simulator, and following problems appeared:

- I've got a view controller f.e "MyViewController", and a custom class which implements some custom component "MyCustomComponent" which is added to "MyViewController". There is a button in MyCustomComponent, and when its touched it peformSelector from MyViewController, and it leads to crash with EXC_BAD something. Same code works on iPhone 4.3 simulator just perfectly. Any ideas?
- Custom navigation bar - doesn't work at all. I'm trying to set custom background implementing UINavigationBar, and overriding drawRect, but it doesn't shows in ios 5.

Comment: Got navigation bar fixed http://weston-fl.com/blog/?p=3024

Comment: OK, so i guess I figrued it out. My console was off, when i reinstalled xcode, so didn't see any error messages. Turned it on now, and got an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency'". Problem was that I was adding MyCustomComponent to MyViewController using self.view=myCustomComponent.view, when I should be doing [self.view addSubview:myCustomCoponent.view], it wasn't an issue in ios 4.3, but seems its a big deal in ios 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so i guess I figrued it out. My console was off, when i reinstalled xcode, so didn't see any error messages. Turned it on now, and got an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency'

Problem was that I was adding MyCustomComponent to MyViewController using

```
self.view=myCustomComponent.view
```

when I should be doing

```
[self.view addSubview:myCustomCoponent.view]
```

it wasn't an issue in ios 4.3, but seems its a big deal in ios 5.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem.

When you create a new Master-Detail Application(without story board), you can see this codes below from AppDelegate.m.

```
 MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

"BE NOT DEPENDENT ON MainWindow"
Just start from your own ViewController and set it to delegate.
And don't forget to unlink view from MainWindow.xib else the view will called 2 times.

Answer (score -1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS implies that the object doesn't exist. Try NSLog-ging the object on which you are performing the performSelector-method.

EDIT: If it crashes when you try logging it, it has been dealloced. Check if you retain the object correctly!

If it is a valid object, try:

```
if(![obj respondsToSelector:@selector(mySelector:)]){NSLog(@"no such method!");}
```

Comment: Sending a message to `nil` is a no-op in Objective-C.

Comment: Object is valid, and object responds to selector, but I still get crashes on pefrormSelector(((

Comment: Does the console say anything?

Comment: Nope, just SIGABRT, thats all.